# Rewrite .php URL with two parameters and redirect old .php URL to new .htm URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I've set RewriteRules in my htaccess file to rewrite my php URLs to SEO friendly .htm ones. Now I have to set 301 Redirect to point the php URLs to the new htm URLs, but cannot find a solution for this. As you maybe guess, I'm not familiar with the rewrite/redirect rules :(
In my htaccess I have this for both the accessory.php and the accessory-details.php files and it works perfect.

```
RewriteRule accessories-(.*)\.htm$ accessories.php?lang=$1
RewriteRule accessory-details-id-(.*)-(.*)\.htm$ accessory-details.php?id=$1&lang=$2
```

The problem is I still can access the php URLs. The php URL have good rankings, so I need this 301 redirect for SEO purposes.
How can I do a rewrite and 301 redirect? Note that some files have one and other files have two GET parameters. I couldn't set a working code myself and this makes me mad.
These are only two examples, there are many similar "pairs" of files on my root, but I think I could manage to adapt the code to the other files, if I could get these two working.

Comment: "some files have one and other files have two GET parameters." - Please give examples of the old and new URLs to which they should be redirected. You are using the very generic pattern `.*` to capture the URL parts - but this is most certainly _too generic_. The regex `(.*)-(.*)` is rather "ambiguous". What are valid `id` and `lang` parameter values?

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite for trying to help :-)
The 'id' parameter is an integer - 1 2, 3, ..., the 'lang' parameter is a string - "en" or "fr". For example:
'accessory-details.php?id=6&lang=en'  (old URL with parameters) and 
'accessory-details-id-6-en.htm' // new SEO friendly URL

Comment: The website is https://www.goldenmaskdetectors.com, if you want to test. 
    https://www.goldenmaskdetectors.com/accessory-details.php?id=6&lang=en and 
    https://www.goldenmaskdetectors.com/accessory-details-id-6-en.htm are both accessible. I want only the .htm file to be accessible and to make a 301 redirect from the php URL to the rewritten .htm URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The 'id' parameter is an integer - 1 2, 3, ..., the 'lang' parameter is a string - "en" or "fr". For example: 'accessory-details.php?id=6&lang=en' (old URL with parameters) and 'accessory-details-id-6-en.htm' // new SEO friendly URL

Your existing regex (subpatterns) are too generic. `.*` matches anything (including the hyphen, which you are using as a delimiter) so results in the regex being rather ambiguous. The regex should be as specific as required to ensure you are not unnecessarily rewriting (and *processing*) URLs which are invalid from the outset.

Assuming your `.htaccess` file and other files are in the document root then try the following instead:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect old URLs (PHP files) to new URLs
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=([a-z]{2})$
RewriteRule ^accessories\.php$ /accessories-%1.htm [QSD,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)&lang=([a-z]{2})$
RewriteRule ^accessory-details\.php$ /accessory-details-%1-%2.htm [QSD,R=301,L]

# Internal rewrites (new URL to file)
RewriteRule ^accessories-([a-z]{2})\.htm$ accessories.php?lang=$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^accessory-details-id-(\d+)-([a-z]{2})\.htm$ accessory-details.php?id=$1&lang=$2 [END]
```

The `END` flag (Apache 2.4) ensures that no further processing occurs after the URL is rewritten - so the rewritten URL is not redirected (during a second phase of processing, as would happen with the `L` (`last`) flag).

These directives also assume that your URLs contain no other URL parameters, other than `id` and `lang` as stated. And are consistently in the order as stated. ie. `id=123&lang=aa`, not `lang=aa&id=123`.

The `%1` and `%2` backreferences contain the values captured from the preceding *CondPattern*.

The `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag on the external redirects is necessary to discard the original query string from the redirect response.

NB: Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues. You will likely need to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: Thank you @MrWhite ! This works fine, with just a small issue, that, I believe, will not cause problems, since I have a sitemap with the canonical URLs: The redirect adds a query at the end of the htm URL and the redirected URL now looks like this:
accessories-en.htm?lang=en
Could this be avoided? I think there will not be a problem with the Google ranking, but will be better without the query, I think.

Comment: @Kiko Sorry, that was an error. You need to add the `QSD` flag to both the external redirects to discard the original query string from the redirect response. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @kiko I've also corrected the regex on the last rule to include the start-of-string anchor (`^`). Although that shouldn't actually make any difference in this case as it happens.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, @MrWhite! Perfect job! Now all works like charm :-)
Thank you!